# Magento 2 where session data is stored (see example)

Tags: magento2, customer, session, quote

I'm trying to figure out how magento is hiding quote ids on client side
I've checked quote mask ids table, but this id is not there, so leaves me to guess its in session data `"jQuery.localStorage.get('mage-cache-storage')"` which gives a cart id thats not in quote table.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Magento 2.4, the `mage-cache-storage` Local Storage Key stores data about the Visitor or Customer, but not about the cart. The following fields are available about the Visitor/Customer (if known):

- billingAddressFromData
- inputFieldEmailValue
- newCustomerBillingAddress
- newCustomerShippingAddress
- selectedBillingAddress
- selectedPaymentMethod
- selectedShippingAddress
- selectedShippingRate
- shippingAddressFromData